# Why do I get 50 rep points for validating my e-mail address on Area 51 but not on other sites?

Tags: discussion, reputation, users

It would be useful for users in other sites who are struggling to get past new-user restrictions...

Comment: Ahhh, so *that's* why I have 151 reputation at Area 51...

Comment: I can see letting someone bypass the new user restrictions if they've confirmed their e-mail, but it's literally 10 rep -- it's a single answer upvote. It's hard to "struggle" for one upvote

Comment: @MichaelMrozek One could argue that for those who are struggling to make it past that barrier, we shouldn't introduce a way to circumvent it.

Comment: @DanielBeck It's not "circumventing" it though; the barrier exists to avoid spam, and if you're bothering to verify your e-mail you're probably not a spammer

Comment: @MichaelMrozek "probably"... well said.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Stack Exchange sites are *more* about the information and the content you post, and *less* about who you are. The reputation allocation reflects that.

But in Area 51, we are asking people to "follow" and "commit" to proposals, so verifying your account identity has value in Area 51. That's why there's a reputation boost for having taken that step. It allows you to reach that next level of participation in the site for having done so.